# What is python 3's equivalent of 1000000000L

Tags: python

I have a python script that ran under python 2 with a variable assignment:

```
xyz = 1000000000L
```

Under python 3, this doesn't seem to be recognized ("invalid syntax"). How do I have to change the assignment so that it will run under python 3?

Comment: In Python 3, all integers are longs. No need for the suffix.

Comment: Simply drop the `L`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem they eventually realized that allowing a vestigial `u` prefix on strings was acceptable, I wonder why they didn't do the same for the `L` suffix on ints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3 `long` was [renamed](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237) to `int`, which is now the only built-in integral type. So you need to just omit the `L`.

Also, if you're fortunate enough to be running Python 3.6+ you can use [underscores](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/) as visual separators in numeric literals:

```
xyz = 1_000_000_000
```

Comment: Only in 3.6 I think? The general answer is just that the L suffix isn't valid anymore and wasn't really really required that often previously anyway.

Comment: Or just `10**9`.

Comment: ...or maybe `1e9`, but that is float, not int